# (XARRAY) ValueError: ('freq', 'dir') must be a permuted list of ('time', 'freq', 'dir'), unless `...` is included

Tags: python-3.x, python-xarray

I'm trying to use module [`wavespectra`](https://github.com/wavespectra/wavespectra/).

I can read the data from the [ndbc](https://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/to_station.shtml) but I can't plot it. Figure below shows that the data is read.

[image: xarray data]

When trying to plot with `a.spec.plot()` I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/guin0x/Harmony_GITHUB/scripts/test.ipynb Cell 4' in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 a.spec.plot()

File ~/env/Harmony/lib/python3.10/site-packages/wavespectra/specarray.py:756, in SpecArray.plot(self, kind, normalised, logradius, as_period, rmin, rmax, show_theta_labels, show_radii_labels, radii_ticks, radii_labels_angle, radii_labels_size, cbar_ticks, cmap, extend, efth_min, **kwargs)
    706 def plot(
    707     self,
    708     kind="contourf",
   (...)
    723     **kwargs
    724 ):
    725     """Plot spectra in polar axis.
    726 
    727     Args:
   (...)
    754 
    755     """
--> 756     return polar_plot(
    757         darr=self._obj.copy(deep=True),
    758         kind=kind,
    759         normalised=normalised,
    760         logradius=logradius,
    761         as_period=as_period,
    762         rmin=rmin,
...
    789         f"{dims_supplied} must be a permuted list of {dims_all}, unless `...` is included"
    790     )
    791 yield from existing_dims

ValueError: ('freq', 'dir') must be a permuted list of ('time', 'freq', 'dir'), unless `...` is included
```

I am not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm trying to follow the [documentation](https://wavespectra.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plotting.html).

Could anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: It seems as though the spectra plug-in can only plot a 2D slice of your data with the dims (freq, dir)  at a time. If you select a single time step eg with `a.isel(time=0).spec.plot()` does that solve the issue?

Comment: Generally though [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Instead, post your code and data objects (eg with `print(ds)`) using a [formatted code block](/help/formatting). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, and for the instructions! Indeed that helps, the plot doesn't look good. But that's another issue :p thanks!

Comment: rolled this into an answer. glad this helped!

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're seeing indicates that the time dimension is not expected by the operation you're calling:

```py
ValueError: ('freq', 'dir') must be a permuted list of ('time', 'freq', 'dir'),
unless `...` is included
```

This probably indicates that the `wavespectra` extension accessor `.spec.plot()` is not expecting to encounter any additional dimensions besides `freq` and `dir`. So you need to somehow reduce the dimensionality of your data, e.g. by extracting a single time slice (e.g. `a.isel(time=0).spec.plot()`) or computing a summary statistic (e.g. `a.mean(dim='time').spec.plot()`). See the xarray guides to [Indexing and Selecting Data](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/latest/user-guide/indexing.html) and [Computation](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/latest/user-guide/computation.html) for more info about available operations.

Note that `wavespectra`'s `spec` accessor is not a part of xarray, so any errors you encounter are due to the xarray integration built into the `wavespectra` library, not an issue with xarray itself, so you might have luck getting additional help by contacting the developers of that library.

Answer (score 0):

The plotting code in wavespectra is a wrapper to xarray plotting methods and some constrains will apply. You must define what you want to plot in your dataset in case you have multiple spectra as in your example. The suggestion from @Michael Delgado is an option by slicing one single time. You could also use `col` / `row` and `col_wrap` / `row_wrap` arguments from xarray to plot multiple times.